# FOSOAuthServerBundle access_token life time

Tags: symfony, oauth, access-token

If someone are looking how to change access_token life time (expires_in) for FOSOAuthServerBundle then here is how to do it:

```
fos_oauth_server:
    service:
        user_provider: fos_user.user_manager
        options:
            access_token_lifetime: 20 #will set token life time to 20 seconds
```

This way you also have possibility to change other options of OAuth2.0 library that is fully used by FOSOAuthServerBundle.

Hope this post saves someone's time ;)
Have a nice time for other important tasks and improvements ;)
Enjoy

Answer (score 5):

is in the official documentation:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration_reference.md

Comment: That's cool. But when it was posted by me, the documentation about this options was empty :-) that's why decided to post here :-) In any case, thanks for sharing this :-)

Answer (score 0):

please run `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod` or `php app/console cache:clear --env=dev` according to your environment after **configuring** *access_token_lifetime* manually to take place the effect!